# Customize Office 365 navigation bar?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to change the looks of the top navigation bar in SharePoint? If I change my theme, it changes for all my Office 365 applications, except for SharePoint. My company has this "theme" going, that does not look good at all with my SharePoint site I am currently designing.

I have no PowerShell or anything, but I do manage my own site completely.

What can I do? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the classic experience in your site in SharePoint online, then you could add the CSS code in master page to customize the top navigation bar.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Branding SharePoint 2013 Top Navigation Menu bar with Custom CSS.](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-top-navigation-bar-branding-css.html)

If you use the modern experience in your site in SharePoint online, then I am afraid there is no method to customize the top navigation bar.